# i have good pressure in bathroom but really bad in kitchen?

Tags: plumbing

i have no presser in the kitchen,while i have good pressure in bathroom.  I replace pressure switches all the time.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Water pressure?  Have you cleaned faucet filters?

Comment: Failing that ^^, take the flexible supply lines loose from the kitchen faucet (do not kink or torque the copper lines, if it has any, while you do). Feed them into a bucket and turn on the valves. If you've got good flow, it's the faucet. If not, either the valve or the pipe has blockage.